# How can I disable any TCP/IP port on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, tcpip, ports

I need help on finding out how to disable any particular TCP/IP port on a Windows box whenever a need arises.

I googled before posting the question and I got links to articles mentioning only

- disabling services for a particular port
- disabling net bios ports
- port forwarding on a router
- etc

But none of these topic cover what I'm looking for.

Comment: Inbound or outbound? Have you configured Windows Firewall?

Answer (score 8):

1. Open **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**
   [image]
2. Select the **Inbound Rules** section
   [image]
3. Create a new rule by clicking **New Rule...**
   [image]
4. In the resulting dialog, chose **Port** as the rule type:
   [image]
5. Now select if the rule should apply to **TCP** or **UDP** packets and what port should be filtered:
   [image]
6. After that you'll want to select to **Block** connections:
   [image]
7. You can now define what types of networks the rule should apply to:
   [image]
8. Now give your rule a name and you're done:
   [image]

Comment: does this work for localhost too? Because I can't block requests to my localhost with this rule unfortunately.